# how to hash a directory

Tags: scripting, macos

looking to compare two directories to make sure they are identical, looking for a script for mac terminal that hash the directory producing a sha 256 hash value that way I can manually verify all exit code related scripts don't seem to work for me

Comment: unfortunately i posted the question in the wrong community so I got some answers that weren't transferable to macOS

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399011/how-to-check-if-2-directories-have-the-same-content/1399013#1399013 was one of the answers I got but was notified that some of the syntax wouldn't translate and anecdotally didn't work for me

Comment: Should two directories that contain the same files but with different names be considered different? What if the difference is in the ownership or permissions or nlinks or extended attributes of the file? In other words, what should the checksum end up containing?

Comment: if I'm reading your response correctly your asking what I'm looking for the cheksum to relay? I copied one directory from my mac to an external hard drive using the cp -r cmd so everything should be identical but for what ever reason if I use diff cmd it will show that there seems to be some files in one that is not in the other so i'm a bit confused. i used the ditto cmd to update the destination folder with files that where added to the original folder but so would that play a factor in why they are not showing as similar

Comment: `autoload zargs; zargs ./**/*(D.) -- sha256sum | sha256sum` from within the top level of that directory would be a good start if you cared only about content and names of regular files only.

Comment: im working with zsh, it doesn't recognize those commands or at least that what its telling me

Comment: `zargs` is autoloadable functions of `zsh`. If your system doesn't have sha256sum, replace with whatever does sha256 sums on your system.

Comment: okay and it laymans terms what will this command do?

Comment: You were the one asking for sha256 sums in the first place!

Comment: im very beginner level when it comes to terminal scripting so don't know all the cmds and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Let the system do the heavy lifting:

```
diff --recursive --brief dir1 dir2    # diff -qr dir1 dir2
```

Comment: its weird I run the script and it will say there are files only in one directory though I copied the directory from the original any reason for this? for context I used the cp -r cmd to copy the directory and the second copy directory is on an external hard drive would that play a factor? would rsync be a better cmd for copying directories so that they are identical

Comment: diff a c > /dev/null && echo Same || echo Different this cmd seems to run but will give a "different" output even though one is an exact copy of the other

Comment: I didn't say `diff a c`, I offered `diff -qr a c`. The `--recursive` (`-r`) and `--brief` (`-q`) flags modify the operation of the command

Comment: yes I know I gave you an answer to what happened when I ran that cmd in the response under your suggestion. the other cmd is one that was suggested to me and wondering if you may have some opinions on why its running the output it is given my conditions i'm working with

Comment: What filesystem have you put on the external disk? Please add this to your question (for example, "The second directory is on an external disk, formatted as ...{whatever}..."), so that everyone can benefit from the updated detail. You don't need to write "Edit" because we can all see the full edit history.

Comment: Also, if my answer doesn't work, please show listings of the two directories, and the exact command you used to compare them. (Tested on a Mac and worked for me.)

Comment: the external drive is formatted as exfat if I run the diff -qr cmd while two identical directories are in the same path then it will have no output which im assuming means no difference but when I have the two identical directories in different paths it wont view them as the same.